# How can i see the exact times push notifications are processed in Notification Hubs?

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to diagnose reliability and performance of a system that delivers push notifications to client apps. Part of the system involves telling an Azure Notification Hub to push. I can see metrics in the classic portal, but no data on exact times the notification was processed or handed off to gcm.

Is such telemetry available? Service Bus Explorer does not appear to be working: the default sas connection string does not seem to give me any metrics to download.

Comment: ``I can see metrics in the classic portal, but no data on exact times the notification was processed or handed off to gcm.``  There are some GCM metrics we can access, do you want **GCM Successful Notifications** metric?

Comment: Yes, but times of when these events took place. Basically, trying to investigate the total latency in the system and the breakdown of where the latencies take place. I have a chain like this WebAPI called by 3rd party--->Message on Azure Queue--->WebJob trigger--->Sends push via Hub--->Gcm---->device

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information by using [Per Message Telemetry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608135.aspx) which is available in [Standard Tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/). You'll get something like this for each push:

```
<NotificationDetails xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NotificationId>{Your message id}</NotificationId>
  <Location>sb://{Your namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{your hub name}/messages/{your message id}?api-version=2015-04</Location>
  <State>Completed</State>
  <EnqueueTime>2015-11-02T21:19:43Z</EnqueueTime>
  <StartTime>2015-11-02T21:19:43.9926996Z</StartTime>
  <EndTime>2015-11-02T21:19:43.9926996Z</EndTime>
  <NotificationBody>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;&lt;toast&gt;&lt;visual&gt;&lt;binding template="ToastText01"&gt;&lt;text id="1"&gt;Hello from a .NET App!&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/binding&gt;&lt;/visual&gt;&lt;/toast&gt;</NotificationBody>
  <TargetPlatforms>windows</TargetPlatforms>
  <WnsOutcomeCounts>
    <Outcome>
      <Name>Success</Name>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </Outcome>
    <Outcome>
      <Name>WrongToken</Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Outcome>
  </WnsOutcomeCounts>
  <PnsErrorDetailsUri>{Blob uri}</PnsErrorDetailsUri>
</NotificationDetails>
```

If you're using direct send, then the `EndTime` there should be what you're looking for once the job is in `Completed` state.

Generally, NH processes all pushes within 1 minute.